# Complex reaction mechanisms in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I would like to draw the figure shown below
[image]

So far I've come so far:
[image]

As you can see, the arrows from the "NAPQI" named molecule, are not really where they belong. I would like to make further arrows from the NAPQI molecule on. Can anyone help?

my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
excretion
\arrow{<-}[90] APAP-sulf
\arrow{<-[SULT][sulfation]}[0,1.3]
\chemname{\chemfig[][]{@{HO}{HO}-[:30]*6(-=-(-NH-[:-30](=[:-90]@{O}{O})-[:30])=-=)}}{Acetaminophen}
\arrow{->[UGT][glucorination]}[0,1.3]APAP-gluc
\arrow {->}[-90] excretion
\arrow{->}[-150,2,opacity=0] \chemname{\chemfig{{O}=[:30]*6(-=-(=N-[:-30](=[:-90]{O})-[:30])-=-)}}{NAPQI}
\arrow{<-[CytP450][N-hydroxylation]}[90]
\arrow{->}[-90, opacity=0]\arrow{->}APAP-S-proteine
\arrow{->}[-90, opacity=0]   
\arrow{<-}APAP-SG    
\schemestop    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=.8cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)=-=(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}}{Glucuronate}\arrow(a--b){<-[UDP-glucuronyltransferase][]}[,2.5]\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}}{Paracétamol}\arrow(@b--c){->[CYP2E1][]}[-90,2.5]\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(=O)-=-(-N-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}}{NAPQ1}\arrow(@c--){->[Zellprobene][]}[,2.5]\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=(-S-Probene)-=(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}
\arrow(@c--){->[GSH][Gluthathion S-transferrase]}[180,2.5]\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=(-SG)-=(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}}{Mercaptsäure}
\arrow(@b--){->[Sulfotransferrase][]}[0,2.5]\chemfig{*6(-(-O-[:0]\chemabove{SO_3}{\hspace{5mm}\ominus})=-=(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:0]C(=[:90]O)-[:0])-=)}
\schemestop
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

The result is
[image]

Comment: I'm missing the NH3 parts. Is it possible to have for the HN... part some sort of macro so it needs not to be repeated?

Comment: You must use the \definesubmol macro (p. 31 of the package documentation).